# Regular Expression to mask any string matching 10 digits only in golang

Tags: regex, go

Since golang regex does not support lookaheads,
I was wondering is there any way i can create a regex that will mask any string having a 10 digit number.

```
func main() {
    s := "arandomsensitive information: 1234567890 this is not senstive: 1234567890000000"
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`\d{10}`)
    s = re.ReplaceAllString(s, "$1**********$2")
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Is it possible to get an output like this
"arandomsensitive information: 1234****** this is not senstive: 1234567890000000"

Also any regex without lookaheads that i can try?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: yes @WiktorStribiżew this answer helps. I was also wondering how can this regex be extended if we also want to search it within the word.
eg: aspacestrippedstring1234567890buttrailingonehouldnotbematchedastitis20characters12345678901234567890 
should return 
aspacestrippedstring1234******buttrailingonehouldnotbematchedastitis20characters12345678901234567890

Comment: That is more difficult because you would need a `(?<!\d)(\d{4})\d{6}(?!\d)` regex and Go regexp does not support lookarounds. Another problem is that [`ReplaceAllStringFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.ReplaceAllStringFunc) does not keep track of captures within a match data object and we are somewhat limited when using [`(^|\D)(\d{4})(\d{6})(\D|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/aXH0P1/1)

Comment: I added another solution for 10-digit number inside any non-digit chars. One flaw: it won't match consecutive numbers.

Comment: yes @WiktorStribiżew, so i extended this with the regex ((\b|\D)\d{4})\d{7}(\b|\D) and it's covering all the scenarios 
The only false positive here is for numbers like 12345678900.122 it will mask as 1234******.122 which is fine given the condition

Comment: Actually, `((\b|\D)\d{4})\d{7}(\b|\D)` will match 11-digit numbers. But suit yourself :) Please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Deleting older comment. 
yes @WiktorStribiżew, so i extended this with the regex ((\b|\D)\d{4})\d{6}(\b|\D) and it's covering all the scenarios The only false positive here is for numbers like 12345678900.122 it will mask as 1234******.122 which is fine given the condition –

Comment: You still can replace `(\b|\D)` with `(\D|^)` and last `(\b|\D)` with `(\D|$)`, the functionality will be the same

Comment: This trims spaces eg:  "this is a sample: 1234567890 to be masked" 
it will print "this is a sample: 1234******to be masked" without the space, whereas expected is  "this is a sample: 1234****** to be masked"

Comment: See my updated answer. The second solution works as expected, too.

Comment: Did you try the above example in comment mentioned? It does not work

Comment: Of couse I did. [Here is the demo](https://play.golang.org/p/8aPqyhd5g3J). **IT WORKS**.

Comment: It should actually be ``regexp.MustCompile(`(\D|^)\d{6}(\d{4}(?:\D|$))`)``, see [demo](https://play.golang.org/p/uEtd3hmH8E_K)

Comment: Perfect @WiktorStribiżew. Thanks both the solution you have given works. This one for masking first 6 digits.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this will fail for following string "1234567890 1234567890 1234567890"

Comment: Right, it is impossible without an input string "tweak". I already mentioned that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61852533/regular-expression-to-mask-any-string-matching-10-digits-only-in-golang?noredirect=1#comment109470562_61852533): "*it won't match consecutive numbers*". It is because you need a lookahead at the end, but RE2 does not support lookaheads. So, there is no pure regex way of solving the problem with consecutive matches like this. **You may run regex replace twice to solve it.** See [the Golang demo](https://play.golang.org/p/-YJudDOxIWw).

Comment: yeah looks like thats the only way

Comment: There is a more complex workaround, but this one is the easiest, also common in the Linux (POSIX) world, with `sed` tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the 10-digit number can only appear in between word boundaries - that is, between characters other than letters, digits or underscores - you may use a simple word boundary approach with `ReplaceAllString`:

```
\b(\d{4})\d{6}\b
```

Replace with `$1******`. See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/Iqe3i2/1).

The `\b(\d{4})\d{6}\b` pattern matches a word boundary first, then matches and captured four digits into Group 1, then matches any six digits and then requires a word boundary position.

See the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/xgU7O5Fd7FB):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    s := "arandomsensitive information: 1234567890 this is not senstive: 1234567890000000"
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`\b(\d{4})\d{6}\b`)
    s = re.ReplaceAllString(s, "$1******")
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

If you need to match the 10-digit number in between any non-digit characters, you may use

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    s := "aspacestrippedstring1234567890buttrailingonehouldnotbematchedastitis20characters12345678901234567890"
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`((?:\D|^)\d{4})\d{6}(\D|$)`)
    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString(s, "$1******$2"))
}
```

See the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/yJ6Pr0Dhbyt)

**NOTE**: Since Golang regex does not support lookarounds, it is impossible to handle consecutive numbers with a regex in a single step. A `(?!\d)` lookahead would make it possible to match both numbers in `1234567890 1234567891` string. So, there is no pure regex way of solving the problem with consecutive matches like this. However, *you may run regex replace twice* to solve it:

```
result := re.ReplaceAllString(re.ReplaceAllString(s, "$1******$2"), "$1******$2")
```

**Regex details**:

- `((?:\D|^)\d{4})`  - Group 1: any non-digit char or start of string and then any 4 digits
- `\d{6}` - any six digits
- `(\D|$)` - Group 2: any non-digit or end of string.