# Match begging and end characters without taking them from another search

Tags: regex, go

Without using regex look around (not supported by go), how can I match beginning and ending characters without taking them from another search.
Ex: Want to match any "dog" or "cat" that has a space, comma, or semicolon and the beginning and end.

So: " dog dog, cat cats; " would match "dog", "dog", "cat". What I have so far (?:[ ,;]|^)(cat|dog)(?:[ ,;]|$) will return "dog" "cat" since the spaces are taken between matches

Comment: Just replace twice. Same trick I used at the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61852533/regular-expression-to-mask-any-string-matching-10-digits-only-in-golang/61852895#61852895).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really only see a few ways of doing this with Go.

Most straightforward would be to just only match one side, and then do a little bit of post regex logic:

https://play.golang.org/p/1_4fi-4kMhi

```
content := []byte("dog dog, cat cats; ")
re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?:[ ,;]|^)(cat|dog)`)
matches := re.FindAllIndex(content, -1)
for _, match := range matches {
    next := string(content[match[1]])
    if next == "," || next == " " || next == ";" {
        fmt.Println(string(content[match[0]:match[1]+1]))
    }
}
```

The other way would be to just duplicate any of your delimiters:

https://play.golang.org/p/krDlmHfepA1

```
content := []byte("dog dog, cat cats; ")
re := regexp.MustCompile(`([ ,;])`)
content = re.ReplaceAll(content, []byte("$1$1"))
fmt.Println(string(content))
re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?:[ ,;]|^)(cat|dog)(?:[ ,;]|$)`)
matches := re.FindAllSubmatch(content, -1)
for _, match := range matches {
    for _, submatch := range match[1:] {
        fmt.Println(string(submatch))    
    }
}
```